# What is the difference between using default charset and using default character set in MySQL while creating database

Tags: mysql, database, character-encoding

I tried using these two SQL statements to create a database:

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dbname` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

and

```sql
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `dbname` DEFAULT CHARSET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;
```

Both of these SQLs got the same result:

```sh
mysql> show create database `dbname`;
+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| Database | Create Database                                                    |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
| dbname   | CREATE DATABASE `dbname` /*!40100 DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 */ |
+----------------------+--------------------------------------------------------+
```

But, there isn't an option named `CHARSET` for creating database in MySQL documentation https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-database.html, I want to know the differences between these two statements.

Comment: *I want to know the differences between these two statements.* `CHARACTER SET` is documented whereas `CHARSET` is not documented but is successfully parsed and applied as an alias of `CHARACTER SET` - this is the only difference.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to find any official documentation about `CHARSET` too but all of the search result return link to `CHARACTER SET`. What I do find is [this MariaDB documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-character-sets-and-collations/#illegal-collation-mix) which have a `CREATE TABLE` query using `CHARSET`. So, I'm guessing `CHARSET` is a valid synonym to `CHARACTER SET`.

FYI: I notice that MySQL have a lot of similar functions but slightly - to moderately different name such as `CURRENT_DATE` and `CURDATE()`. Most of these functions have almost identical name only differs slightly in spelling. However, there are two functions that I know in particular have totally different names and noticeable difference in length but perform exactly the same operation. These functions are `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `NOW()`. Here is [a demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ki5JCyxGD4sGfP5t6nTgv2/0).

Comment: *different name such as CURRENT_DATE and CURDATE()* This is [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-date): `CURRENT_DATE and CURRENT_DATE() are synonyms for CURDATE()`. This is [documented](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_current-timestamp) too: `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() are synonyms for NOW().` Read manuals - they're rulezz.